# Does simulator supports background modes

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to start a background voice process. Does simulator supports background modes in iOS.

This is my code to start a background process.But its not working.when i press the home button recording stops.

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports multitasking
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance
            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object
            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
                //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
            }];
            //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                //Perform your tasks that your application requires
                NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
                NSString *pollingTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                                           target:self
                                                                         selector:@selector(recordPauseTapped:)
                                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                                          repeats:YES];
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use CTRL+K to show code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534095/audio-recording-in-background-on-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848172/ios-multitasking-for-an-audio-recording-application

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2778018?start=0&tstart=0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024999/background-audio-recording-in-ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276611/record-voice-in-backgroundwhen-i-tapped-home-button-using-avaudiorecorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the device supports multitasking or not use the following code:-

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
```

Although there are some hardware limitations of simulator which includes:-

-Accelerometer
-Gyroscope
-Camera
-Proximity Sensor
-Microphone Input
To test your app on a device, you must be a member of the iOS Developer Program. To learn more about enrolling in the iOS Developer Program, see “Enrolling in an Apple Developer Program and Accessing Its Tools” in App Distribution Guide.
You can not test all these features on a simulator

Comment: @pooja_chaudhary Seems like you're the same person as "pooja chaudhary" answering here. Please use only one account.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't support background modes.

Answer (score 0):

Background modes are supported on simulators, however your condition(as below) will fail on simulator & hence the issue.

> if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])

Comment: Then how should i check the background modes on simulator

Comment: You may have to provision the code to execute irrespective of simulator or device. Either remove the condition checking the device capability or add additional condition for simulator.

Comment: Have you put a break point inside this method and checked if it executes on simulator?

Comment: Yes this code executes on simulator,but practically its not working

Answer (score -1):

Yes, background mode is supported by simulator but you have to enable it in project settings. You recommend to look at that link below.

[Background download sample](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)